# I want to make new column with Logic?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

**Given:** `Employee ID` and `Manager ID`.

```
| Employee ID | Manager ID |
|:-----------:|:----------:|
| E068        | E067       |
| E071        | E067       |
| E229        | E069       |
| E248        | E144       |
| E226        | E223       |
| E236        | E241       |
| E066        | E001       |
| E067        | E001       |
| E144        | E001       |
| E223        | E001       |
```

**Problem Statement:**

This problem is to identify the **Head of Manager** by using Employee and their Manager data.

**About:**
We have an `Employee ID` and their `Manager ID`. Please note that Manager ID are from `Employee ID`. Since each manager has one Manager above their level.

1. First, we'll take all UNIQUE ID in `Manager ID` column.
2. Then for each **ID** from `Manager ID` column, we will look for their respective `Manager ID`(Manager)
3. Then we will create a new column say `Level 1` we will put manager for each `Manager ID` on their respective cell.
4. Similarly, we will repeat the above 3 processes again till there is no `Manager ID` for that particular ID.
5. This way we can identify the `Head of Manager`.

I am able to solve the problem by filtering the excel but it takes a lot of time. Hence, I am looking for an optimal solution that can help me out.

**Expected Output:**

```
| Employee ID | Manager ID | Level 1 | Level 2 | Head of Manager |
|:-----------:|:----------:|---------|---------|-----------------|
| E068        | E067       | E001    |         | E001            |
| E071        | E067       | E001    |         | E001            |
| E229        | E069       | E066    | E001    | E001            |
| E248        | E144       | E001    |         | E001            |
| E226        | E223       | E001    |         | E001            |
| E236        | E241       |         |         | E241            |
| E066        | E001       |         |         | E001            |
| E067        | E001       |         |         | E001            |
| E144        | E001       |         |         | E001            |
| E223        | E001       |         |         | E001            |
```

> The `Employee ID` column contain **UNIQUE ID** while `Manager ID` contain **DUPLICATES ID**.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Does the given table show the expected result or what you already got?

Comment: @dirdi Yes, And thanks for your query I have updated my question now.

Comment: How many levels do you expect maximum in your hierarchy?

Comment: @MátéJuhász It depends upon the organization. As in some, there would be 4 hierarchy then Head of that department. Well, in this case, there are **2 Level**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use VLOOKUP for identifying manager's manager, need to create as many columns as many levels you have in your hierarchy.

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,$A:$B,2,FALSE),"")`

[image]

Comment: Thank you @MátéJuhász this is working